# Listview is setting text only for first position

Tags: android, android-listview

Listview is setting the filename only in first position. Even though on clicking any positions of the listview it sets the filename for the first position only. Please let me know what changes i need to make so that filename will be set properly on clicked item only instead of first item always. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try logging your position number in onClick method

Comment: ivDocument.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
       Log.d("**Postion", "Postion: "+position);
          (( DocumentActivity ) context).Document(position);
          // tvDocName.setText(s);
      }
    });

Comment: onActivityResult did you are getting same position??

Comment: if I am not wrong you want that document path in listview at that postion??

Comment: if yes then you can do
Survey_vehiclepojo selected=mylist.get(position);
selected.setPath(path);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you can set path adding above code in selectedFile method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done same with in Recycle view I am sharing my project code with you

```
package com.deepak.myapplication;

public class DocumentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
ImageView toolbar_back;
TextView next, tvDocName;
RecyclerView listView;
ArrayList<Survey_vehiclepojo> mylist = new ArrayList();
My_document_adapter adapter;
private int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //toolbar_back = ( ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back);
    //toolbar_back.setOnClickListener(this);

    //next = ( TextView ) findViewById(R.id.next);
    //next.setOnClickListener(this);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

    mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("Pay Slip", "file1"));
    mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("Insurance", "file2"));
    mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("NA Certificate", "file3"));
    mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("NA 1", "file3"));
    mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("NA 2", "file3"));
    mylist.add(new Survey_vehiclepojo("NA 3", "file3"));
    listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new My_document_adapter(mylist, DocumentActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    /*case R.id.toolbar_back:
    finish();
    break;
    case R.id.next:
    Intent n=new Intent(DocumentActivity.this, Loan_checklistActivity.class);
    startActivity(n);
    break;
    }*/
    }
}

public void Document(int pos) {
    position = pos;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    selectedFile(data, requestCode);
}

private void selectedFile(Intent data, int position) {
    String displayName = null;
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String uriString = null;

        if (uri != null) {
            uriString = uri.toString();
        }
        File myFile = new File(uriString);
        String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();

        if (uriString != null) {
            if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                try (Cursor cursor = DocumentActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        tvDocName = findViewById(R.id.tvDocName);
                        Survey_vehiclepojo selected = mylist.get(position);
                        selected.setFile1(displayName);

                        //My_document_adapter.display(displayName,position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
            displayName = myFile.getName();
            tvDocName = findViewById(R.id.tvDocName);
            Survey_vehiclepojo selected = mylist.get(position);
            selected.setFile1(displayName);
            //My_document_adapter.display(displayName,position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is  Adapter

```
class My_document_adapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<My_document_adapter.ViewHolder>{
ArrayList<Survey_vehiclepojo> mylist;
DocumentActivity documentActivity;

public My_document_adapter(ArrayList<Survey_vehiclepojo> mylist, 
DocumentActivity documentActivity) {
    this.mylist = mylist;
    this.documentActivity = documentActivity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public My_document_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new My_document_adapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull My_document_adapter.ViewHolder holder, 
final int position) {

    holder.name.setText("name"+position);
    holder.ivDocument.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
   @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("**Postion", "Postion: "+position);
        documentActivity.Document(position);

    } });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mylist.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final TextView tvDocName,name;
    ImageView ivDocument;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);


        tvDocName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDocName);

        ivDocument = view.findViewById(R.id.ivDocument);
    }
  }
 }
```

and my file is selecting  see this screenshot[image]

Comment: No its not even setting the filename

Comment: can you exact tell me what you want you want file text to be shown or file as Image ???

Comment: I just want the filename to be shown and not the image.

Comment: even for me it show when i debug but its not coming in the display. I will post layout_activity also, give me a min.

Comment: In a textview in that list. (for each item)